# What are the differences between a Lightning Container and a Canvas App?

Tags: canvas, iframe, lightning-container

Both `lightning:container` and Canvas Apps (which themselves can be embedded into Lightning components using `force:canvasApp`) seem to be doing similar things. Both of them allow you to embed external applications into Salesforce, and do it within an iframe. Both allow two-way communication between Salesforce and the application in the iframe. What are the differences between them and how can I decide which one is right for which use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lightning:container` uses a [static resource](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_static_resources_manage.htm&type=5) hosted in Salesforce, while `force:canvasApp` allows you to embed any site that uses the [Canvas API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/). The difference is location. The one that you use is the one that makes the most sense. Almost all apps would presumably be better suited as a force:canvasApp, but if all you have is source code (e.g. there's no server), Salesforce can host the application code.